# Concrete footers, adding height to existing

Tags: concrete

I have an existing deck with posts in footers. The footers are below grade and the posts were backfilled with dirt around them before a concrete patio was poured around the posts. The posts are showing signs of rotting and bowing. The need to be replaced.

Can I temporarily jack up the deck, cut the existing patio and remove the existing posts, chatting them down flush to the footer and then add height to the existing footer by pouring concrete on top of them the make them the height of the patio?

I was going to cut patio, dig down to top of footer, cut existing post off, drill rebar into footer, place forming tube, pour concrete to patio height. Cure. Install new 6*6 Simpson brackets into the top of the footer and set new posts, attach to beam and remove temporary supports.  Is this acceptable?

Comment: If you are asking us if you can do the work, we. do not know your skills. Is it acceptable ? possibly it is

Comment: Consider using form tube https://www.homedepot.com/p/SAKRETE-8-in-x-48-in-Concrete-Form-Tube-65470075/100321209

Comment: Get a dig bar and try to remove the rotten deck pole from the footers. It will make for a sturdier support.